# InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

I get following exception, while running a MapReduce job:

```
15/12/25 16:00:07 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
15/12/25 16:00:07 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
15/12/25 16:00:07 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/C:/Users/HARSH/workspace1/hadoop/words.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:885)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:447)
    at hadoop.wordcount.main(wordcount.java:70)
```

Can anyone please help? Is the problem in the package file? 
Arguments I have given is "input.txt output".

Here is the code:

```
package hadoop;     

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class wordcount {

    static public class wordmap extends  Mapper<IntWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>
    {
        public void map(IntWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            Text keys = new Text();
            IntWritable one= new IntWritable(1);
            StringTokenizer tokens= new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            while(tokens.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                keys.set(tokens.nextToken());
                context.write(keys, one);
            }
        }
    }

    static public class wordred extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
    {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            int sum=0;
            for (IntWritable count : values) 
            {
                sum=sum+ count.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Configuration conf=new Configuration();
        Job job= new Job(conf,"wordcount");
        job.setJarByClass(wordcount.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        job.setMapperClass(wordmap.class);
        job.setReducerClass(wordred.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Also I am getting "Job cannot be resolved to a type" error

Answer (score 1):

It's not a compilation error.
As the exception clearly states, your application cannot find the file **C:/Users/HARSH/workspace1/hadoop/words.txt**

Check that:

- file exists and the path is correct (try using absolute paths)
- you have access permission
- no other program has the file open

Comment: i have given the file words.txt  as command line agrument.   In this format" words.txt outputdirectory_name"

Comment: SIr ,How to resolve "Job cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: @HARSH once you fixed the file path problem, open another question for that problem.

Comment: Sir what does these exceptions means???org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:885)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:779)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:447)
    at hadoop.wordcount.main(wordcount.java:70)

Comment: Sir, i specified in run confguration as "\user\HARSH\input\words.txt\user\HARSH\output" @Alessandro Da Rugna.. Now its just giving my arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at the output  directory(code line containing args[1]). What should I do now?

Comment: @HARSH arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: you have to specify the output file too

Comment: please help  for this exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/UnmodifiableMap

Comment: @HARSH http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776795/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-in-hadoop-basics-mapreduce-program

Comment: the link there were not useful, non of them has collection.map.unmodifiedmap..can you help me with some other links